# Python Selenium - TESTNG equivalent setup to run execute tests on different browsers in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testng, browser-automation

I am looking for a Below TestNG specific logic to run tests on different browsers in a single run with parameterisation,

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Test Suite">
 <test name = " chrome">
      <parameter name = "browserType" value="chrome" />
      <classes>
         <class name = "runners.RunnerTest"/>
      </classes>    
    </test>
 <test name = " edge">
      <parameter name = "browserType" value="edge" />
      <classes>
         <class name = "runners.RunnerTest"/>
      </classes>    
    </test>
<test name = " firefox">
      <parameter name = "browserType" value="firefox" />
      <classes>
         <class name = "runners.RunnerTest"/>
      </classes>    
    </test>
```

```
public class RunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests  {
        public final static ThreadLocal<String> BROWSER = new ThreadLocal<>();
        @Parameters("browserType")
        @BeforeClass
        public void beforeClass(@Optional String browser) {
            ConfigLoader.initializePropertyfile();
            RunnerTest.BROWSER.set(browser);
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) Python Selenium solution for that.

`pip install seleniumbase`, and then run the following script with `python`:

```py
from parameterized import parameterized
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pytest import main
    main([__file__, "-n3"])

class TestBrowser():
    @parameterized.expand(
        [["chrome"], ["firefox"], ["edge"]]
    )
    def test_parameterized_browser(self, browser):
        driver = Driver(browser=browser)
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.quit()
```

It will open up three different browsers in parallel, which will close after 3 seconds. If the drivers aren't already on the System PATH, they will automatically be downloaded, but it will take some additional seconds for that.

Comment: Seems OP added _Python_ tag by mistake as the question is Java/TestNG based.

Comment: its python specific question, gave Java-testng reference to get specific requirement